# Copy file from one container to another container in Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

imagin I have a blob in a container in an Azure Data Lake gen2:

Container:test1
Directory:TextFiles
File: example.txt

I would like to copy `example.txt` from `test1` container with exact the same path to `test2` container

Container:test2
Directory:TextFiles
File: example.txt

How can I do that in c#?

Comment: What type of application are you using? Azure Function? Console App? Web App? Desktop App? Do you want it to be automatic process or user defined?

Comment: Azure Function. actually automatic

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this using an Azure Function, you will need to create a function that runs off off a BlobTrigger listening to the `Test1` container. You can create a second blob binding to the output container and simply process them.

The function code would look something like this.

```
public static async Task CopyTextFiles(
    [BlobTrigger("TextFiles/{name}.{extension}", Connection = "Container1ConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob inputFile, string name, string extension, ILogger log,
    [Blob("TextFiles/{name}.{extension}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "Container2ConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob outputFile)
{
    var inputFileStream = new MemoryStream();
    await inputFile.DownloadToStreamAsync(inputFileStream);
    inputFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    await outputFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(inputFileStream);
    
    //I'd recommend looking at StartCopyAsync() method as this is probably what you need.
    //Personally I have never used it.
}
```

The connection property of the binding is in the `local.settings.json` file and can be obtained from the Azure portal in the 'Access keys' section of the storage account.

It should look something similar to this

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME;AccountKey=SOME-ACCOUNT-KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

However I believe in Visual Studio you can configure this in Visual Studio when you create an Blob Trigger Azure Function from the template.

Hope this helps, any questions let me know!

You can also find out more about the Triggers and Bindings and the different types you can use from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can copy from source to destination in ADLS Gen2 between 2 different containers.

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Replace with your ADLS Gen2 account information
        string accountName = "<your-account-name>";
        string accountKey = "<your-account-key-or-SAS-token>";

        // Replace with your source and destination paths
        string sourceFilePath = "<source-file-path>";
        string destinationFilePath = "<destination-file-path>";

        var serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net"), new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey));

        var sourceFileClient = serviceClient.GetFileClient(sourceFilePath);
        var destinationFileClient = serviceClient.GetFileClient(destinationFilePath);

        await CopyFileAsync(sourceFileClient, destinationFileClient);
    }

    static async Task CopyFileAsync(DataLakeFileClient sourceFileClient, DataLakeFileClient destinationFileClient)
    {
        // Open a read stream from the source file
        using (var sourceStream = await sourceFileClient.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            // Open a write stream to the destination file
            using (var destinationStream = await destinationFileClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true))
            {
                // Copy data from the source stream to the destination stream
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```